# Partitioning Bootcamp partition without OS Disk

Tags: windows-7, macos, partitioning, boot-camp

I would like to repartition my hard drive so that my mac partition has more space as opposed to my windows partition. I, unfortunately, no longer have the operating disk. Is it possible to resize the partition? Must I resize it on the Windows side and then extend the mac side on from the mac partition?

Answer (score 1):

Try [EASEUS Partition manager](http://www.partition-tool.com/). It works very well.